# How do I make an Icon look like glowing water in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, objects, node-editor

so i'm trying to get an icon of mine too look like it is water that is glowing it doesn't have to be transparent or anything. I just want the object to have the illusion of glowing water. i have tried mixing and adding shaders and a few different textures but can't seem to get anything that resembles glowing water. any help would be very much appreciated. i am still a very big noob at blender (only been learning it a hour here and there between my job and relationship for the past week) so something very simple would be great. I have also included a picture of the icon below, its the grey middle, (just a simple extruded circle that has been smoothed, with a Torus wrapped around it with a emit shader on it) Thanks in advance :D in the meantime i'll keep tinkering with it and update if i figure something out and hopefully help someone else with this type of situation[image: The Icon i'm trying to get is the grey middle middle there]

Comment: Hello, welcome to Blender.SE! So just to be clear, you want to add the water material to the gray circle in the middle, right?

Comment: What is "*glowing water*" and what does it look like? It is a good idea to show reference images of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @SilverWolf Yes but giving it kind of a glowing as well, maybe not crazy glowing but just enough to see that it is glowing.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos kind of like the glowing water in this simple kids science experiment https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjdxtGC7fPfAhWDy4MKHc-tD5IQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjmcrempsblog.com%2F2016%2F12%2F27%2Fscience-experiment-for-kids-how-to-make-glowing-water%2F&psig=AOvVaw1w1Zh1Pcq3G2zJ9u-YznqO&ust=1547781345571771

Answer (score 2):

So i got something kinda figured out that i wanted to share everyone. Not exactly how I imagined it but its good enough that i'm ok with it and think it looks good enough looking kind of watery and it glows a little bit with no lighting in the world which looks pretty cool, Although if someone has something that looks better please still post up an answer i would love to see some different takes on this.  Plus i'm going to be animating it so it appears to have water moving over the texture. just a short 8 second long animation which is why the mapping node is there. Have a great day guys and Happy Creating!!! [image: What i came up with, looks pretty cool i think.]